# dojo tree selected node issue

Tags: dojo, tree

I am trying to change the style of the dijit tree(release 1.10) selected tree node. I am changing the CSS style of .claro .dijitTreeRowSelected. I change the attribute color to

```
color: #0096c9 !important;
```

Still the selected node text is showing black color. When investigated the text color is being picked from class "dijitTreeContent". Can any one help to change the color of the selected node and also what is the wrong with above aproach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are showing (.claro .dijitTreeRowSelected) should work, it does for me with this:

```
.claro .dijitTreeRowSelected { color: red }
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle which will make the selected label red, and the hovered one green: 
http://jsfiddle.net/edchat/dox42qye/15/

Can you setup a jsfiddle showing your problem if it is not working for you?

Comment: Yes, you were right, by overriding the (.claro .dijitTreeRowSelected ) it should work. But in my case the class dijitTreeContent (which contain default attributes) was having color attributes. After removing the color attributes from dijitTreeContent it worked fine. Thanks for help.